# what is callback method of Picasso download bitmap?

Tags: android, picasso

I was using this library (https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery) for image downloading and displaying. there is a callback method. Inside of this method, i was checking that bitmap is larger than screen size or not. if bitmap is larger then screen size, then i had divided bitmap into 5 bitmap parts and displaying in 5 imageview so resolution was good.

```
  final AQuery[] aq = {new AQuery(hh.imageview), new AQuery(hh.imageview3), new AQuery(hh.thumbnail3),
                        new AQuery(hh.thumbnail4), new AQuery(hh.thumbnail5), new AQuery(hh.thumbnail6)};
                final Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[6];
                aq[0].id(hh.imageview).image(url, false, true, 0, 0, new BitmapAjaxCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void callback(String url, ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, AjaxStatus status) {

                        if(bm != null) {
                            if(bm.getHeight()>=maxTextureSize){
                                int h = bm.getHeight();
                                int w = bm.getWidth();

                               /* bitmap[0] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0 , 0, w, h/6);
                                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap[0]);
                                bitmap[1] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0 , bitmap[0].getHeight(),
                                        w, h/6);
                                aq[1].id(hh.imageview3).image(bitmap[1]);
                                bitmap[2] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0 , bitmap[0].getHeight() + bitmap[1].getHeight(),
                                        w, h/6);
                                aq[2].id(hh.thumbnail3).image(bitmap[2]);
                                bitmap[3] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, bitmap[0].getHeight() + bitmap[1].getHeight() + bitmap[2].getHeight(),
                                        w, h/6);
                                aq[3].id(hh.thumbnail4).image(bitmap[3]);
                                bitmap[4] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, bitmap[0].getHeight() + bitmap[1].getHeight() + bitmap[2].getHeight()+bitmap[3].getHeight(),
                                        w, h/6);
                                aq[4].id(hh.thumbnail5).image(bitmap[4]);
                                bitmap[5] = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, bitmap[0].getHeight() + bitmap[1].getHeight() + bitmap[2].getHeight()+bitmap[3].getHeight()+bitmap[4].getHeight()
                                        , w, h/6);
                                aq[5].id(hh.thumbnail6).image(bitmap[5]);*/
                           /* }
                            else if(bm.getWidth()>=maxTextureSize){
                                bm =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, maxTextureSize, bm.getHeight(), true);
                                iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                            } else {
                                iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                                hh.imageview3.setImageDrawable(null);
                                hh.thumbnail3.setImageDrawable(null);
                                hh.thumbnail4.setImageDrawable(null);
                                hh.thumbnail5.setImageDrawable(null);
                                hh.thumbnail6.setImageDrawable(null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                if(bitmap[0] != null) {
                    bitmap[0].recycle();
                    bitmap[0] = null;
                }
                if(bitmap[1] != null) {
                    bitmap[1].recycle();
                    bitmap[1] = null;
                }
                if(bitmap[2] != null) {
                    bitmap[2].recycle();
                    bitmap[2] = null;
                }
                if(bitmap[3] != null) {
                    bitmap[3].recycle();
                    bitmap[3] = null;
                }
                if(bitmap[4] != null) {
                    bitmap[4].recycle();
                    bitmap[4] = null;
                }
                if(bitmap[5] != null) {
                    bitmap[5].recycle();
                    bitmap[5] = null;
                }
```

Now i have moved Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) library. and i am looking same above logic in this library also. but unable to find how i can do it? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            //do smth when picture is loaded successfully

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            //do smth when there is picture loading error
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#into-android.widget.ImageView-com.squareup.picasso.Callback-

The `.into` method provides a second argument which is a callback to success and failure.

```
public void into(android.widget.ImageView target,
             Callback callback)
```

Also you can use `.transform(new ImageTransformation())` method for change size